# Move snackbar above bottomNavigationView

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-snackbar

I have a BottomNavigationView inside a CoordinatorLayout with and I want to move snackbar above bottomNavigationView but snackbar visible behind bottomNavigationView

My navigationView when scroll show/hide when hide snack bar visible

activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/main_coordinatorLayout"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:fontFamily="@font/open_sans_bold"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="143dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="14dp" />

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/main_viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?actionBarSize"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="auto"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_color"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_color"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_menu" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

fragment.java

```
Snackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.main_coordinatorLayout),"Message",Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).show();
```

[image]

[image]

**Sorry for my bad English**

Comment: You need to provide a `ViewGroup` that doesn't contain BottomNav, try providing R.id.main_viewpager & see it that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the google material component library you can use `Snackbar` with anchor method like below:

```java
    Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(view,"text",Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);
    snackbar.setAnchorView(bottomNavigationView);
    snackbar.show();
```